# What is the best web UI for choosing a range on a form?

Tags: html, range

I have a typical form with dropdown choices, freeform textboxes and textarea for large fields.

I now need to add a range for things like this.

Start / End Time
Start / End Day
Low Bid / High Bid

I can do this by simply having 2 different controls and have folks choose seperately but i was thinking there might be a better way given the validation functionality seems generic  (i don't want anyone to be able to choose a value for the End / High number that is lower than the Low / Start number and visa versa.

What is the best UI for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While I have no idea how to implement it, I saw the following on kayak.com recently and it might work for your purposes. There are sliders for Min and Max. IN this case, as you are sliding it displays a graph showing the price of flights for that selection. I've seen similar on ebay motors and other places.

I prefer this UI over having separate controls for Min and Max (or Start and End, etc.) The entire schedule or range is on a single control and the user has immediate feedback on the consequences of their changes.

[image: sliders]

Answer (score 1):

I think the page on [forms from Dive Into HTML5](http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html) will be helpful to you...just don't overlook the part where it touches on using feature detection (Modernizr) and a fallback.